# JS Jquery Removing hyphen from search/filter input (numbers only)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search input field with some connected javascript that I use as a filter on my page. It basically takes the input and searches in a h3 tag for the  name and description but then also searches a table (specifically the tbody -> tr) and if a row doesn't contain a match it hides it.

I've come to one problem with the contents of the table body/rows. Each row has a number, usually 6 digits with a hyphen after 4, but not always (1234-56, 9876-54, etc.).

The problem is: If you search the numbers with the hyphen, it filters properly and only shows that number but if you just type the 6 digits with no hyphen it hides everything since it didn't technically find a match due to it searching exact strings.

I've found a few methods of doing this but they only apply to the filter variable, but I need some help with this even if it's just a small workaround. Basically, when looking in the tbody/tr for a match, I need it to ignore the hyphen. So whether I type 123456 or 1234-56, it will show only the rows that have 1234-56 for the match. I hope that makes sense.

The Javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#srch-term").keyup(function(){
//For entered search values
// Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
var search_regex = new RegExp(filter, "i");

// Loop through the main container as well as the table body and row that contains the match
$(".group-container").each(function(){
    //check if filter matches the group name or description
    var group_name = $(this).children('h3').text()
    var group_description = $(this).children('.uk-text-muted').text()

    if(group_name.search(search_regex)>=0 || group_description.search(search_regex)>=0){ // filter matches
        $(this).show() // show group
        $(this).find("tbody tr").show() // and all children
        return // skip tr filtering
    }

    var no_matches = true

    $(this).find("tbody tr").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().replace('Available','').search(search_regex) < 0) {
            $(this).hide();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            count++;
            no_matches = false
        }
    });

    if(no_matches){ // if no tr matched the search either, hide whole group
        $(this).hide();
    }

    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you search the numbers with the hyphen, it filters properly and
>   only shows that number but if you just type the 6 digits with no
>   hyphen it hides everything since it didn't technically find a match
>   due to it searching exact strings.

If you only want to do digit based search then remove the non-digit characters from your grid's text while for comparison using

```
.replace(/\D/g, "");
```

and make it

```
var group_name = $(this).children('h3').text().replace(/\D/g, "");
var group_description = $(this).children('.uk-text-muted').text().replace(/\D/g, "");
```

and later

```
if ($(this).text().replace(/\D/g,'').search(search_regex) < 0) {
        $(this).hide();
 }
```

Comment: I may just be confused, but I'm not sure if that's exactly where I was headed. The user can also search by sofa, loveseat, chair, etc. But if they search by item number then they will either search 123456 or 1234-56, so I still need the existing text based search, just that if they do enter numbers then it would pull out that hyphen

Comment: So, you want to prep your data for searching differently based on what user is going to search? You can check if the input was all numbers or not before doing this specific `replace` I have given above.